# Is it possible to safely park a bicycle near the entrance of the Ouwehands Dierenpark?

Tags: netherlands, bicycles, zoos

I plan to visit [Ouwehands Dierenpark](https://www.ouwehand.nl/en/) with a friend, and to move more quickly around we plan to use bicycles and carry them with us on trains.

Is it possible to safely park a bicycle near the entrance of the park? Or would it be more sensible to leave them elsewhere?

I tried looking with Google Maps and Street View, but I could not really locate a spot dedicated for them (as opposed to the large car parking lot east of the entrance).

Comment: It is the Netherlands, I expect a bike rack where you can lock your bike to a post at best. Would that do or are your bikes in 'need guarded inside parking' category?

Comment: Remember that only a folded folding bike can be taken on the train for free and also only those can be taken in peak hours. If you bring a full size bike you can not travel before 9:00, nor between 16:00 and 18:30, you need to buy a (day) ticket for the bike(s)  at €6.90 (2019) and you can find the space for bikes in the train full and having to wait for the next train.

Comment: Less restrictions on time but more bikes in summer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a dedicated spot for bicycles at the entrance of the parking lot. During my last visit (Spring 2017, coincidentally just after the [pandas](https://www.ouwehand.nl/en/discover/pandasia) arrived), it was more or less guarded, and there's a lot of traffic during the opening hours anyway, so I'd say your bikes are safe.

Here is a picture of it on [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.9557572,5.59166,3a,45.9y,74.79h,80.51t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sF_EipKJ1h6OqktdUrS5LXQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656). Of course, remember to bring your locks with you.

[image]

Another option would be to *not* bring your bikes, as the zoo is only [a kilometer](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Rhenen,+3911+BK+Rhenen/Rhenen,+Ouwehands+Dierenpark,+3911+AV+Rhenen/@51.9566602,5.5798013,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c6546427c48a21:0xa4998caf29647da1!2m2!1d5.5782055!2d51.9578083!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c6548ba940abe9:0x64cc664f4b4bef69!2m2!1d5.590607!2d51.955533!3e2), so about 10 minutes walking, from the local train station. This will save you a [€ 6.90 train ticket for your bicycle](https://www.ns.nl/en/travel-information/bikes-on-the-train.html), and as @Willeke mentioned in the comments, you can only bring a (regular) bike during off-peak hours and in the weekend.